# What is the purpose of "typeof" in members in TypeScript typings?

Tags: typescript, electron, typescript-typings, .d.ts

The Electron typescript definitions contain the following interface:

```
interface MainInterface extends CommonInterface {
  // I understand these
  app: App;
  autoUpdater: AutoUpdater;
  // But not these
  BrowserView: typeof BrowserView;
  BrowserWindow: typeof BrowserWindow;
  ClientRequest: typeof ClientRequest;
  ...
}
```

What does `typeof XX` mean in this context? AFAIK `typeof` returns the string name of the type, e.g. the above is equivalent to

```
BrowserView: "BrowserView";
```

If this is the case, then what is the purpose of the member definitions that use `typeof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in a type annotation like in the example above, the `typeof` operator gives the type of a value. If applied to a variable, it gives the type of the variable. If applied to the class it give the type of the class (not the instance type, but the type representing the class constructor and the static methods.

```
class Foo {
  static method(){}
}

let foo: typeof Foo;
foo.method();
new foo()

let o = 1
let oo: typeof o
```

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, defining a class results in two interfaces:

1. The class interface
2. The instance interface

The trouble is, only the instance interface gets the name of the class. In order to access the class interface (to do things like `new MyClass()` or `MyClass.staticProperty`), you have to use `typeof`.